# rabbitmq AlreadyClosedException in Masstransit 6.2.3

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm using rabbitmq to create the bus.

After upgrading from 6.2.2 to 6.2.3, I'm getting the AlreadyClosedException in my sagas. It seems to relate to message re-delivery as when I turn re-delivery off then these exceptions go away.

Re-delivery config

```
rec.UseScheduledRedelivery(r =>
            {
                r.Handle<Exception>(IsTransientException);
                r.Ignore<Exception>(IsHarmlessException);
                r.Intervals(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(FirstRedeliveryIntervalInSeconds),
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(SecondRedeliveryIntervalInSeconds),
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ThirdRedeliveryIntervalInSeconds));
            });
```

Error tack trace:

> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.AlreadyClosedException: Already closed: The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=406, text='PRECONDITION_FAILED - invalid expiration '-34318': {value_negative,-34318}', classId=60, methodId=40
>      at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SessionBase.Transmit(Command cmd)
>      at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.ModelBase.TransmitAndEnqueue(Command cmd, IRpcContinuation k)
>      at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.ModelBase.ModelRpc(MethodBase method, ContentHeaderBase header, Byte[] body)
>      at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Model._Private_ExchangeDeclare(String exchange, String type, Boolean passive, Boolean durable, Boolean autoDelete, Boolean internal, Boolean nowait, IDictionary`2 arguments)
>      at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.ModelBase.ExchangeDeclare(String exchange, String type, Boolean durable, Boolean autoDelete, IDictionary`2 arguments)
>      at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Contexts.RabbitMqModelContext.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.b__0()
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Pipeline.ConfigureTopologyFilter`1.ConfigureTopology(ModelContext context)
>      at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Pipeline.ConfigureTopologyFilter`1.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<-Send>b__0>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at GreenPipes.PipeExtensions.OneTimeSetup[T](PipeContext context, Func`2 setupMethod, PayloadFactory`1 payloadFactory)
>      at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Pipeline.ConfigureTopologyFilter`1.GreenPipes.IFilter<MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.ModelContext>.Send(ModelContext context, IPipe`1 next)
>      at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Transport.RabbitMqMoveTransport.Move(ReceiveContext context, Action`2 preSend)
>      at MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.ErrorTransportFilter.GreenPipes.IFilter<MassTransit.ExceptionReceiveContext>.Send(ExceptionReceiveContext context, IPipe`1 next)
>      at MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.GenerateFaultFilter.GreenPipes.IFilter.Send(ExceptionReceiveContext context, IPipe`1 next)
>      at GreenPipes.Filters.RescueFilter`2.GreenPipes.IFilter.Send(TContext context, IPipe`1 next)
>      at MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.DeadLetterFilter.GreenPipes.IFilter<MassTransit.ReceiveContext>.Send(ReceiveContext context, IPipe`1 next)
>      at MassTransit.Transports.ReceivePipeDispatcher.Dispatch(ReceiveContext context, ReceiveLockContext receiveLock)
>      at MassTransit.Transports.ReceivePipeDispatcher.Dispatch(ReceiveContext context, ReceiveLockContext receiveLock)
>      at MassTransit.Transports.ReceivePipeDispatcher.Dispatch(ReceiveContext context, ReceiveLockContext receiveLock)
>      at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Pipeline.RabbitMqBasicConsumer.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()

Also:

> ---> MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.MessageNotConfirmedException: rabbitmq://mq/scheduler => The message was not confirmed: PRECONDITION_FAILED - invalid expiration '-34318': {value_negative,-34318}
>      at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Contexts.RabbitMqModelContext.MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.ModelContext.BasicPublishAsync(String exchange, String routingKey, Boolean mandatory, IBasicProperties basicProperties, Byte[] body, Boolean awaitAck)
>      at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Transport.RabbitMqSendTransport.SendPipe`1.Send(ModelContext modelContext)
>      at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Transport.RabbitMqSendTransport.SendPipe`1.Send(ModelContext modelContext)
>      at GreenPipes.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.GreenPipes.IPipeContextSource<TContext>.Send(IPipe`1 pipe, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at GreenPipes.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.GreenPipes.IPipeContextSource<TContext>.Send(IPipe`1 pipe, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at GreenPipes.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.GreenPipes.IPipeContextSource<TContext>.Send(IPipe`1 pipe, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at MassTransit.Scheduling.EndpointScheduleMessageProvider.ScheduleSend[T](ScheduleMessage`1 message, IPipe`1 pipe, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at MassTransit.Scheduling.BaseScheduleMessageProvider.MassTransit.Scheduling.IScheduleMessageProvider.ScheduleSend[T](Uri destinationAddress, DateTime scheduledTime, Task`1 message, IPipe`1 pipe, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.RedeliveryRetryFilter`2.Send(TContext context, IPipe`1 next)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Comment: What is your `.UseScheduledRedelivery` statement configuration?

Comment: @ChrisPatterson edited question to add re-delivery config

Comment: Issue created: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/1787